# Habilitar próximo passo de Bootstrap Wizard se checkbox estiver marcado

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer uma verificação com um `Bootstrap Wizard` que estou usando, preciso que os passos sejam habilitados se determinados `checks` estiverem marcados, senão estiverem o passo seguinte não poderá ser habilitado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho esses passos no formulário:

```
<div class="form-bootstrapWizard">
<ul class="bootstrapWizard form-wizard">
    <li class="active" data-target="#step1">
        <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="step">1</span> <span class="title">Termo 1</span> </a>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#step2">
        <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="step">2</span> <span class="title">Termo 2</span> </a>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#step3">
        <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="step">3</span> <span class="title">Termo 3</span> </a>
    </li>
    <li data-target="#step4">
        <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="step">4</span> <span class="title">Salvar</span> </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

A minha tentativa em fazer essa verificação está assim:

```
if($("#CheckTermo1").is(':checked')){   
    if("data-target" == "#tab2"){                   
        $(".next").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $(".next").attr("disabled",false);  
    }
}
```

Tenho os `CheckTermo1` que marcado deverá habilitar o `step2`, o `CheckTermo2` habilitará o `step3`e o `CheckTermo3` habilitará o `step4`.

Os checks estão assim:

```
<input name="CheckTermo1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0" id="CheckTermo1" value="0" required>
<input name="CheckTermo2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0" id="CheckTermo2" value="0" required>
<input name="CheckTermo3" type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0" id="CheckTermo3" value="0" required>
```

Comment: Onde tem essa classe `.next`?

Comment: Olá @Sam, essa classe está no botão:                   <li class="next">
                   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg txt-color-darken"> Próximo </a>
                  </li>
Mas não tem nada a ver com a minha tentativa.

Comment: Então no caso, vc quer alterar qual div terá a classe `class="active"` de acordo com o checkbox marcado?

Comment: Não sei bem se seria isso, mas ao clicar no check a navegação acima ficaria habilitada.

Comment: Mas o data-target está como `#step2` e não como `#tab2`. O `#tab2` está no href. Tem algo a ver?

Comment: Tenta percorrer a lista de `li`. 
`$( ".form-wizard> li" ).each(function( index ) {
          let target = $(this).data('target')
          if(target == '#tab2'){
            // seu codigo
         }
     });` dentro do `if($("#CheckTermo1").is(':checked')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma, verificando se o checkbox está marcado e habilitando ou desabilitando o botão next. Segundo a documentação, para desabilitar o botão, basta adicionar a classe `.disabled`.

Pode usar um event handler genérico em vez de criar um `if` para cada coisa. Usando o método `onNext` do plugin, pode usar um callback para disparar o evento change manualmente. Coloquei um delay de 100ms no setTimeout porque ao clicar no next, o evento é disparado antes da mudança do painel ativo. Veja:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
   var checks = $(".checkbox[name^=CheckTermo]");
   
   $('.form-bootstrapWizard').bootstrapWizard({
      onNext: function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
            checks.trigger("change");
         }, 100);
         return verifica();
      },
      onTabClick: function(){
         return verifica();
      }
   });

   function verifica(){
      var tab_ativa = $(".tab-content .active");
      var check = tab_ativa.find(".checkbox[name^=CheckTermo]");

      if( check.is(':checked') ){
         $(".next").removeClass("disabled");
         $(".form-wizard .active").next().removeClass("disabled");
         return true;
      }else{
         $(".next").addClass("disabled");
         $(".form-wizard .active").prev().addClass("disabled");
         return false;
      }
   }
   
   checks.on("change", verifica);
   checks.trigger("change");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/1.2/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-bootstrapWizard">

   <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <ul class="bootstrapWizard form-wizard">
                <li class="active" data-target="#tab1">
                    <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="step">1</span> <span class="title">Termo 1</span> </a>
                </li>
                <li data-target="#tab2" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="step">2</span> <span class="title">Termo 2</span> </a>
                </li>
                <li data-target="#tab3" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="step">3</span> <span class="title">Termo 3</span> </a>
                </li>
                <li data-target="#tab4" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab"> <span class="step">4</span> <span class="title">Salvar</span> </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div></div></div>
   <div class="tab-content">
       <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            1<input name="CheckTermo1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0" id="CheckTermo1" value="0" required>
       </div>
       <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            2<input name="CheckTermo2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0" id="CheckTermo2" value="0" required>
       </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            3<input name="CheckTermo3" type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0" id="CheckTermo3" value="0" required>
       </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
            salvar
       </div>
      <ul class="pager wizard">
         <li class="next"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-lg txt-color-darken"> Próximo </a> </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá @Sam, valeu pelas dicas, mas estou com um problema agora, a navegação superior está com um box azul e a navegação ficou meio bagunçada, mas o código em si funcionou legal.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vdS4.png

Comment: Que estranho rs.. vc mexeu alguma coisa no HTML ou no CSS?

Comment: Olá @Sam, cara, não mexi em nada, mas fiz uns teste, fui tirando o código JS que me passou e o form fica com o layout correto.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo usando os [Pills](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior) do bootstrap.

Como estás usando `links`, para realizar a navegação, não é possível aplicar o efeito de `disabled` que é aplicado nos botões. Para chegar nesse efeito, defini os links sem o atributo `href` e os adicionei conforme os inputs fossem checados.

Abaixo está o resultado:

```js
let $termo1 = $('#termo1'),
    $termo2 = $('#termo2');
    
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($termo1.is(':checked')) $('#nav-termo2').attr("href","#termo2Conteudo");
    
    else  $('#nav-termo2').removeAttr("href");
    
    if($termo2.is(':checked')) $('#nav-termo3').attr("href","#termo3Conteudo");
    
    else  $('#nav-termo3').removeAttr("href");
});
```

```css
a:not([href]):hover {
    border-color: transparent !important;  
    cursor: no-drop;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-termo1" data-toggle="tab" href="#termo1Conteudo" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Termo 1</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-termo2" data-toggle="tab"  role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Termo 2</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-termo3" data-toggle="tab"  role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Termo 3</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="termo1Conteudo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">Termo 1 <br> <br>
     <input id="termo1"  type="checkbox" /> <label>Aceito os termos do serviço </label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="termo2Conteudo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">Termo 2 <br><br>
  <input id="termo2" type="checkbox" /> <label>Aceito os termos do serviço </label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="termo3Conteudo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">Termo 3</div>
</div>
```

Acrescentei o `CSS` para zerar a borda dos elementos que não possuírem o `href`  e alterar o cursor do mouse para dar um efeito de "desabilitado".